# How to chart detected activities on the hour using Chart.js

Tags: jquery, html, chart.js, chart.js2

I have this process that runs every 10 minutes to check for activities from another process, if it detects any activity it will add to the database the date, time and an "A" for been active. 
On the next 10 minutes when it runs again, if the activity is gone, it will add another record in the database with the date, time and a "N" for normal. If the activity persists on the next check it will not add another record in the database until otherwise.
 
Then I have in the database a record showing that yesterday at "2017-03-21 22:30:05" it detected activity, added "A", this activity persisted till "2017-03-22 01:15:10", when no activity was detected during the check, adding another record with the "2017-03-22 01:15:10" date,time and a letter "N".
I am trying having a line chart showing normal activity and maybe dropping down this line showing the time of the day that it detects any activity.

If anyone has done anything like that using Chart.js the help will be very appreciated, I cant see how I could have this data mapped on the chart to show when it detects any activity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpreted your question correctly, here is an option that you could use.  Before jumping straight to the example, let me explain the approach.

First, your requirement is a bit challenging because this would require using a "category" scale on the y-axis along with a "time" scale on the x-axis.  This is a challenge because line charts typically have a "category", "linear", or "time" x-axis and a numerical based scale (e.g. linear, logarithmic, etc.) on the y-axis.

Therefore, to overcome this, I had to use a "linear" scale on the y-axis but use some callbacks to make it appear as if it was actually a "category" scale.  By the way, I tried adding a "category" scale on the y-axis, but could never get a chart to render (so I don't think it is possible).

Since you did not provide an exact example of how your data is stored, I had to make some assumptions for my mock data.  Regardless of how it is actually stored, the approach would be to process the data to convert it into a format that chart.js can understand.  In my example, I have done this using a function called `prepareDataForChart`.

Here is the final chart configuration.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "Object 1",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.white,
      pointRadius: 0,
      steppedLine: true,
      data: prepareDataForChart(mockedActivityData),
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Object Activity State Over Time'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      callbacks: {
        // since we mapped the eventState to a numerical value,
        // let's convert that back to a text value when the tooltip
        // is displayed
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          if (tooltipItem.yLabel === 1) {
            return 'Normal';
          } else if (tooltipItem.yLabel === 2) {
            return 'Active';
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
       type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'minute',
          displayFormats: {
            minute: 'lll',
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'lll',
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Time',
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Activity State',
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 3,
          stepSize: 1,
          // since we mapped the eventState to a numerical value,
          // let's convert that back to a text value to display 
          // on the y-axis (and also hide all other tick labels)
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            if (value === 2) {
              return 'Active';
            } if (value === 1) {
              return 'Normal';
            } else {
              return ' ';
            }
          },
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

And because it's always nice to be able to actually see something, here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/Vpxjed).

Comment: Hi, your approach is great! This is a sample of my data 2017-03-15 21:55 N
2017-03-15 20:05 A
2017-03-15 05:45 N
2017-03-15 05:40 A

Comment: Hi, your approach is great! This is a sample of my data 2017-03-15 21:55 N
2017-03-15 20:05 A
2017-03-15 05:45 N
2017-03-15 05:40 A
 - When I look at it,  I was thinking about having the bottom line with a date range for the day -> 2017-03-15 and drop down the line where the times from my data would match on the day, is it possible?

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean.  You should be able to take the code I provided and modify it for your needs.  You can easily modify the x axis if that is what you mean (check out the [time scale options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale))

Comment: @jordanwillis Loved your answer. Very informative. Helped me out a bit. Do you mind helping me out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050304/chart-js-time-chart-not-displaying-properly)?