# 'Chart.js' time chart not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

So I'm trying to create a simple chart using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). The chart  consists of price values for the y-axis and time values for the x-axis. The data is fetched from an API.

The y-axis value are displayed properly, but for the x-values they appear condensed. These are the options I'm passing into the chart:

```
options: {
        title: {
          display: false
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            ticks: {
              source: 'data',
              autoSkip: true,
              autoSkipPadding: 50
            },
            time: {
              parser: 'HH:mm',
              tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm',
              unit: 'minute',
              stepSize: 10,
              displayFormats: {
                'minute': 'HH:mm',
                'hour': 'HH:mm'
              }
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return '$' + value;
              }
            }
          }]
        }
}
```

I've tried adjusting the step size, but it's not working. For some strange reason, the first label on the x-axis is **15:14** no matter how much I change the data. What could be the issue?

The full code can be found [here.](https://codepen.io/michaelbukachi/pen/baWMKa)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `parser` doesn't really work well with. simply remove `parser` in the option, you can see the clear result.

```
time: {
  //parser: 'HH:mm',
  tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm',
  unit: 'minute',
  stepSize: 10,
  displayFormats: {
    'minute': 'HH:mm',
    'hour': 'HH:mm'
  }
}
```

Comment: That fixes the condensed issue. But how come the labels only show time between four minutes, when the dataset covers an hour??